# Как сравнить DOM элемент с HTML тегом в js?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
galery.addEventListener('click', function(el){  
//по клику на родителя хочу проверить ребёнок=img? 
    if (el.target == '<img>'){
        console.log('это картинка') 
    } else {
        console.log('это что-то другое')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (e.target.tagName === "IMG") {
```

Answer (score 0):

если применимо к вашим данным то точнее будет

```
if (el.tagName == 'IMG'){
        console.log('это картинка') 
    } else {
        console.log('это что-то другое')
    }
```